How to create list animation like IOS does for its notification list in flutter
I want to create list animation just like iOS does for it notification list using flutter.
the only difference is I want to show the list from top of screen not bottom
for reference I have added the image of notification list in iOS
enter image description here
I have tried several methods like using stack and list but not able to produce the same.
Please help

this is os specific and does not belong to you

@WodotaML Is there a way to even create a look a like list. if not the same

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

No, there is no way to do it
